# Интернационализация в проекте Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, i18n, vuetify

```
 headers: [
                    {text: 'Должность', align: 'left', value: 'employeeName'},
                    {text: 'ФИО на русском языке', align: 'left', value: 'ruName'},
                    {text: 'ФИО на казахском языке', align: 'left', value: 'kzName'},
                    {text: 'ФИО на английском языке', align: 'left', value: 'enName'}
                ],
            }
```

Вот есть такой массив думал как сделать для него интернационализацию, пробовал вот так:
`{this.$i18n.text: 'Должность', align: 'left', value: 'employeeName'},` но не получилось

```
export default {
        name: 'EmployeesPanel',
        data() {
            return {
                isEdit: false,
                id: '',
                employeeName: '',
                ruName: '',
                kzName: '',
                enName: '',
                dialog: false,
                selected: [],
                search: '',
                headers: [

                    {text: 'Должность', align: 'left', value: 'employeeName'},
                    {text: 'ФИО на русском языке', align: 'left', value: 'ruName'},
                    {text: 'ФИО на казахском языке', align: 'left', value: 'kzName'},
                    {text: 'ФИО на английском языке', align: 'left', value: 'enName'}
                ],
            }
        },
```

Вот мой шаблон:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-card flat>
            <v-toolbar flat card prominent class="no-padding-toolbar">
                <v-toolbar-items>
                    <v-tooltip bottom>
                        <v-btn flat slot="activator" @click="dialog = true">
                            <v-icon medium>add</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                        <span>{{ $t('Добавить сотрудника')}}</span>
                    </v-tooltip>
                    <v-tooltip bottom>
                        <v-btn flat slot="activator" @click="delEmployees()">
                            <v-icon medium>delete</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                        <span>{{ $t('Удалить сотрудника') }}</span>
                    </v-tooltip>
                </v-toolbar-items>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-text-field
                        v-model="search"
                        append-icon="search"
                        :label="$t('Поиск')"
                        single-line
                        hide-details>
                </v-text-field>
            </v-toolbar>
            <v-divider>
            </v-divider>

            <v-data-table
                    :headers="headers"
                    :items="employees"
                    :search="search"
                    v-model="selected"
                    item-key="employeeName"
                    :no-data-text="$t('Нет данных')"
                    :no-results-text="$t('Не найдены значения')"
                    hide-actions select-all
                    class="fixed-headers">
                <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                    <td style="width: 48px; max-width: 48px;">
                        <v-checkbox v-model="props.selected" primary hide-details></v-checkbox>
                    </td>

                    <td><strong>{{props.item.employeeName}}</strong></td>
                    <td>{{ props.item.ruName}}</td>
                    <td>{{ props.item.kzName}}</td>
                    <td>{{ props.item.enName}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <v-layout align-center justify-space-around row fill-height>
                            <v-icon medium @click="editItem(props.item)">
                                edit
                            </v-icon>
                            <v-icon medium @click="deleteItem(props.item)">
                                delete
                            </v-icon>
                        </v-layout>
                    </td>
                </template>
            </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
            <v-card>
                <v-form ref="form">
                    <v-card-text>
                        <v-container grid-list-md>
                            <v-layout wrap>
                                <v-flex xs12>
                                    <v-text-field label="Должность" required v-model="employeeName">$t{{"Должность"}}</v-text-field>
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12>
                                    <v-text-field label="ФИО сотрудника на русском" v-model="ruName"
                                                  required></v-text-field>
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12>
                                    <v-text-field label="ФИО сотрудника на казахском" v-model="kzName"
                                                  required></v-text-field>
                                </v-flex>
                                <v-flex xs12>
                                    <v-text-field label="ФИО сотрудника на английском" required
                                                  v-model="enName"></v-text-field>
                                </v-flex>
                            </v-layout>
                        </v-container>
                    </v-card-text>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="closeMeth" closeMethod>Закрыть</v-btn>
                        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="addEmployee">Сохранить</v-btn>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-form>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

В `$t()` указывается путь до перевода. Пример:

**ru.json**

```
{
  entity: {
    user: "Пользователь"
  }
}
```

**Использование**

```
<span>{{ $t("entity.user") }}</span>
```

Вам нужно обрабатывать массив перед отображением, где вы настроите переводы и прочие операции с данными, если они должны иметь отличный от дефолтного вид.

Пример:

```
computed: {
  filteredData: {
    return [{
      label: this.$t("path.to.translate")
    }]
  }
}
```